# Create heat map from RMSD values

Tags: visualization

After looking through these forums for answers that could work for my problem, I could not find anything. 
I want to make a heat map comparing values that are in a nested list. 
That is, I have a nested list of size n x n, and each position in the list is a rational number. How could I make a heat map comparing the greater/lesser of these numbers. The higher numbers would be one color and the lower would be another.

An example first three lines of a list of Length 9 is:

```
{{0., 2.03181, 10.9162, 9.81852, 19.9333, 9.74689, 0.826292, 1.61575, 
  6.11642}, {2.52762, 0., 12.3072, 13.0194, 5.9971, 20.1544, 2.1197, 
  0.611078, 5.01625}, {17.5098, 6.42256, 0., 5.32809, 7.09947, 
  22.5269, 5.43391, 5.56034, 0.48698}}
```

All assistance is appreciated.

Best,

CK

Comment: Would ArrayPlot@yourList work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is in the docs* and might be what you want:

(* the catch is you have to know that this is what you need to be able to find it in the docs -- it is not necessarily intuitive for a new user to go to array plot for this solution)

[image]

or you can blend between two colours:

```
ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {10, 20}], ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Yellow, Purple}, #1] &)]
```

[image]

or make a binary choice:

```
ArrayPlot[{{0., 2.03181, 10.9162, 9.81852, 19.9333, 9.74689, 0.826292,
    1.61575, 6.11642}, {2.52762, 0., 12.3072, 13.0194, 5.9971, 
   20.1544, 2.1197, 0.611078, 5.01625}, {17.5098, 6.42256, 0., 
   5.32809, 7.09947, 22.5269, 5.43391, 5.56034, 0.48698}}, 
 ColorFunction -> (If[#1 > 10, Purple, Yellow] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

`ColorFunctionScaling` is an option that by default is `True` and means that the values in your list are scaled. There may be occasions where you want to apply your own scaling function. You would do this as a pure function for `ColorFunction`.

Here is default scaling using a "wimbledon" gradient (green-purple)

```
ArrayPlot[{{0., 2.03181, 10.9162, 9.81852, 19.9333, 9.74689, 0.826292,
    1.61575, 6.11642}, {2.52762, 0., 12.3072, 13.0194, 5.9971, 
   20.1544, 2.1197, 0.611078, 5.01625}, {17.5098, 6.42256, 0., 
   5.32809, 7.09947, 22.5269, 5.43391, 5.56034, 0.48698}}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Green, Purple}, #1] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

[image]

Here is a new plot, this time scaling your numbers between 0 and 40.

```
ArrayPlot[{{0., 2.03181, 10.9162, 9.81852, 19.9333, 9.74689, 0.826292,
    1.61575, 6.11642}, {2.52762, 0., 12.3072, 13.0194, 5.9971, 
   20.1544, 2.1197, 0.611078, 5.01625}, {17.5098, 6.42256, 0., 
   5.32809, 7.09947, 22.5269, 5.43391, 5.56034, 0.48698}}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Green, Purple}, Rescale[#1, {0, 40}]] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]